# Add method to string prototype in JS-Interpreter

Tags: javascript, node.js, interpreter

I am wondering if there is a way to add new methods to prototype of string in [Neil Fraser's JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter). The [documentation](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html) has no example for this and I am not really able to figure it out by the source code.

I expect (if there is a way) to be something similar to adding API calls to the interpreter's global object during creation.

What I have tried is the following:

```js
const interpreter = require('js-interpreter');

var initFunc = function (interpreter, globalObject) {
  var stringPrototype = interpreter.nativeToPseudo(String.prototype);

  var stringGreetWrapper = function greet() {
    return "Hi " + this + "!";
  };

  interpreter.setProperty(stringPrototype, 'greet', interpreter.createNativeFunction(stringGreetWrapper));
};
        
var code = 'function foo(name) {return name.greet();}';
var myInterpreter = new interpreter(code, initFunc);
myInterpreter.appendCode('foo("John");');
myInterpreter.run();
var res = myIntepreter.value;
```

But it gives me an error: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: The answer to the linked question is working in general, but I am trying to extend the string prototype in the interpreter itself.

Comment: Please note that snippets use the browser's JavaScript engine to run JavaScript. I've removed the snippet wrapper since clicking "Run code snippet" did not generate the error desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it very like that code adding `alert`, see inline comments (you can condense the code a bit, I wanted to show each step explicitly):

```js
const initFunc = (interpreter, globalObject) => {
    // Get the interpreter's `String` constructor
    const stringFunction = interpreter.getProperty(globalObject, "String");
    // Get its `prototype` object
    const stringProto = interpreter.getProperty(stringFunction, "prototype");
    // Define our new function
    const newMethod = function () {
        // Note that we have to convert what we get to a primitive
        const str = String(this);
        // Show what we got
        console.log(`newMethod called on string ${JSON.stringify(str)}`);
    };
    // Add the method to the interpreter's `String.prototype`;
    // make it non-enumerable like most prototype methods are
    interpreter.setProperty(
        stringProto,
        "newMethod",
        interpreter.createNativeFunction(newMethod),
        Interpreter.NONENUMERABLE_DESCRIPTOR
    );
};

// Define and run some code using the new method
const myInterpreter = new Interpreter(`"somestring".newMethod();`, initFunc);
myInterpreter.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/interpreter.js"></script>
<script src="https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/acorn.js"></script>
```